# If the two selected balls have different colors, what is the probability that the selected ball from the first box was green?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> There are two boxes.  The first box contains $2$ red balls and $5$ green balls; the second box contains $8$ red balls and $10$ green balls.  One ball is selected from each box.  Each ball is equally likely to be selected.  If the two selected balls have different colors, what is the probability that the selected ball from the first box was green? 
>  (a) $0.47619$ 
>  (b) $0.66667$ 
>  (c) $0.33333$ 
>  (d) $0.41667$

I can't really find an answer. I tried using Bayes' theorem.  However, I wasn't met with an choice, $P(B_1 \mid G)$. I can't have any idea to find it. I got about $0.425$ for answer. However, nothing of those options.

Comment: Show us how you applied Bayes theorem and how you arrived at 0.425?

Comment: I need P(G|B1) according to question

P(G|B1) = P(B1|G) * P(G) / P(B1)

G for green, B1 for Box 1

Now thing is i found out P(G) because its 15 green balls out of 25 balls overall
Thus P(G) = 15/25
P(B1) = 0.5 (it's two boxes)

Left is P(B1|G) I assumed its P(B1) * P(G) but I don't think its correct

Comment: The probability you are asked to find is $P(\text{first ball is green} \mid \text{two balls have different colors})$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question overall

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched and readers who rely on screen readers may not be able to read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of conditional probability $(P(A \mid B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$), we have
\begin{align}
& P(\text{first ball is green} \mid \text{two balls have different colors})
\\
&= \frac{P(\text{two balls have different colors}, \text{first ball is green})}{P(\text{two balls have different colors})}
\\
&= \frac{P(\text{first green, second red})}{P(\text{first green, second red}) + P(\text{first red, second green})}
\\
&= \frac{(5/7)(8/18)}{(5/7)(8/18) + (2/7)(10/18)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the colors are different, there were 20 ways to draw red/green and 40 ways to draw green red, so 40 out of 60 ways of 66.6666… % the number from the first box is green.